# Как получить список всех каналов на youtube?

Tags: c#, youtube-api

Собственно вопрос в шапке. Удастся ли через api с учетом квот? Или лучше реализовывать как html-парсер? Если парсер, то подскажите примерный алгоритм(вообще в ютубе не шарю))

Comment: @Александр_Ли абсолютно все каналы? https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list

Comment: да, как бы жестко это не звучало)